# trying to recolorize monochrome planetary image

Tags: photoshop

I have a little project going on where I am taking monochrome planetary images and coloring them to as true to life as possible.  Affinity Photo is my primary editor although I am familiar with Photoshop since I used it in a college course some time ago.

My first task was to simply lift the planet from the black background so that it would be on its own layer.  The planet is a monochrome Jupiter.  I then decided to add a gradient map adjustment layer and then apply color palette values from an online source for the planet.  However, the result was horrible and none of the ten color values for the gradient made much impact on the monochrome planet.  I tried changing the colors of each gradient tab and also one of several blending modes, but to no avail.

I decided to abandon the gradient map adjustment layer and use just gradient.  After creating the customized color palette for the gradient once again, I am getting somewhat better results, but I still don't have much control with the ballpark scaling values and applying/ reapplying what I hope is the correct sized gradient.  This method may work, however, but I am unable to actually bend the gradient colors to find the slightly arced Jupiter bands.

What is the best way to do this coloring?

Comment: I think your question is off-topic here. This site is about photography. Photoshop is a graphics editor - just because something can be done in Photoshop does not make it photography. You could try the Stack Exchange site for [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) maybe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about photography.